# Chrome Browser and Java Message Passing

Tags: java, api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have developed a Chrome extension and it captures some data in a webpage. 
My ultimate goal is to pass this final result to my Java Application.
I have following few options in my mind, but I was not able to find any resources for them yet.

1. Access the `localStorage` externally.
2. Run Chrome browser through the Java app, So I guess we have the control of its data.
3. If no API found, write the result to a file and access it from the
   Java App.

Is there any API to achieve any of the first 2 options? Or any other interface other than the file system?

I checked with [berkelium](http://code.google.com/p/berkelium-java/) and The [Chromium Embedded Framework](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/). But they are just chrome wrappers, and we cannot run a chrome instance from it.

### **Edit**

For the 2nd option I tried with Selenium Webdriver, but I think it hasn't any method to access the localStorage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for **[Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/nativeMessaging/)**, which allows communication between a Chrome Extension and a native application (e.g. a Java Desktop Application).

There are plenty of question here on SO regarding the implementation of Native Messaging and there is, also, the **["official" example](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/nativeMessaging/)**.

---

<sub>I suggest the above solution, but if your application will heavily interact with the extension (and you feel like reverse engineering) there is the open-source **[NetBeans Connector Chrome Extension][3]**, which uses a different approach (Sockets or WebSockets - I am not sure).  
Take a look at **[this answer][4]** for info on how to get at the sources.</sub>

Comment: **Native Messaging** is 100% matching with my requirements :-) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a limitation preventing you from exposing a REST API with your java application?

Comment: I believe OP referes to a Desktop Java App (not a JavaEE-based web-app).

Comment: thanks for the replies. Yes this is a Java Desktop application

Comment: Yeah but I would just import `HttpServer`, open a port and send data from my extension to `localhost:<port>`. That seems like the path of least resistance to me.